# Is null a class in java?

Tags: java, null

According to,
[http://www.freshvanilla.org:8080/display/www/Java+Interview+Questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20100131074659/http://www.freshvanilla.org:8080/display/www/Java+Interview+Questions)

Under

> Which class is the superclass of every
>   class?

`null` seems to be the answer.

I found that

```
 new Object().getClass().getSuperClass()
```

verifies the answer as correct.
But can `null` be considered a class?

I see all primitive data types are represented as `Class` objects from
[java.lang.Class's documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100305034912/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I simply love your `new Object().getClass().getSuperClass()
 == null`.

Comment: Whoever wrote that page doesn't really know what they're talking about. I'd discount the whole thing.

As for original question, it should be reworded "which class is the superclass of every class except itself?"

Comment: @KevinBourrillion +1 to your comment for suggesting that original question should better be reworded to "Which class is the superclass of every class except itself?"

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion Trick questions make GREAT interview questions.  Not to discount the possibility that the person who wrote this question didn't think it through that far, but I can promise you that if you responded (whether or not they were expecting it) with "There isn't one.  The closest would be the Object class, but it does not inherit from itself, and it is still part of 'all classes,' therefore no class is superclass to all classes."  - that kind of response is EXACTLY what many interviewers seek when coming up with their questions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That is a screwy interview question. I am pretty sure the answer they are looking for is `Object`, not `null`. `null` is not a class. What it means when `getSuperClass` returns `null` is "there is no superclass". `null` is merely a special value that a reference can have. If `null` were a class, you would be able to instantiate objects of type `null`. It would also not make sense to assign `null` to a reference of any other type.

Answer (score 8):

I think Object class is the answer.

from javadoc.

```
new Object().getClass().getSuperClass()
```

**If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned.**
it doesn't mean that null is supperclass.

If null is a class, i think it must be Null.
null is not a class.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "If null is a class, it must be called Null" :-)
I believe here you meant 'Class' class is the answer. It seems the getSuperClass() method present in 'Class' class returns the superclass of the class represented by the referenced object and if the class represented by that object is Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then this getSuperClass() method simply returns null.

Answer (score 6):

In java java.lang.Object is the parent (root) of all other Objects and has no predecessor.

Null isn't an object at all it indicates that there is no object available (null reference).

See also [JLS Chapter 4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the `Class` class is *itself* a class. So when you call `c.getClass()` you're getting back an *instance* of the `Class` class. So because there *is no* super class of `Object`, the `getSuperClass()` method cannot return anything so it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast the Null object to other primitive types and you don't inherit from it. The top level class in Java is Object.

Answer (score 0):

Object is the super class of all the class and null is object references

Answer (score 0):

Poorly worded question. Only the 'simple' answer is correct as an answer to the question. The others are just confusing.